# How to make a spreadsheet in Angular (incl insert rows, filters, sorting, pin columns)?

Tags: angular, spreadsheet

I want to make a table with features like insert rows, filters, sorting and pin columns. I searched for libraries, but most of them are not for free. How can I implement the features on a table?

I'm new in Angular. Maybe there is an easy solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeng is a good provider of components, for free ofc. For your purpose Datatable is for now a really good solution:

https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/datatable